# Is there a way to check a form when it actually changes?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, onchange

I realize there is a `onchange` event attribute for the purpose of detecting a change in a form and performing a certain javascript function. However, this requires the user to click outside of the form field, making it very similar to `onblur`.

Is there actually a way to perform a function when a form changes, without having to wait for the user to click outside of the form?

*I know you can use JavaScript timeouts to check the form every few milliseconds, but I would prefer a solution without them. Also, I am not limited to just form elements; I'm okay with using `contenteditable` `divs`.*

I don't think a code is necessary, but I can add a sample code of what I mean if needed.

Comment: So I would run a script after every key press? Interesting idea. If you write a formal response, I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery has powerful functions that deliver what you're after, but if you just need to run a simple script, you can use functions such as onkeydown and onkeypress.

```
<input type="text" onkeydown="myFunction()">
```

Sources:

[W3 Schools - OnKeyPress](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp)

[W3 Schools - OnKeyDown](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeydown.asp)

Answer (score 1):

If I were to do this myself I would listen to the change event on the inputs of a form. Personally I think this would be easier for you to do using jQuery.

```
$('form input, form select').change(function() {
    console.log('form has been changed');
});
```

Comment: Don't forget select lists, they don't render as input tags!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ensure you catch when any type of input in your form changes (ie. checkbox, select lists, radio buttons etc and not just text) then you could use the following snippet I put together (assuming you're using jQuery)

```
$('form input[type=text]').keyup(formUpdated);

$('form input[type!=text], form select').change(formUpdated);

function formUpdated() {
    alert('input changed');
}
```

You can see it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/26CpH/2/).

This is all just a nice way of removing the need for this:

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="formUpdated();">

<select onchange="formUpdated();">
</select>

<input type="radio" onchange="formUpdated();">

<input type="checkbox" onchange="formUpdated();">
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, I am not in a position to use jQuery for my current project, but this definitely helps! +1.